# Logged out automatically

Tags: logout

Following a power outage, Ubuntu logs me out of my account around 15 seconds after signing in. I just don't understand it.

What could be causing this, how to solve it?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? have you checked the session log
 `~/.xsession-errors`?